# Watering pitcher plants(Nepenthes)

Tags: watering, nepenthes

I have decided to start growing carnivorous plants(specifically, Nepenthes(pitcher plant)) in pots and got seeds and carnivorous plant soil. Now, I want to plant them into pots, but what type of water is confusing. If using distilled, reverse osmosis, or rain water(I don't get much rain), can I use any brand distilled water if I chose distilled; can I use a water filter to water the pitchers?

Answer (score 2):

Distilled, demineralized, and RO water should all work fine.
As for filters, as long as they leave the water with an extremely low ppm (~50 ppm) they should be fine.

Just one more thing: don't refill the pitchers themselves, they're evolved to have a certain amount of digestive enzymes inside, not water (which is why they have lids, to prevent rain from getting inside :D ), as they tend to rot quickly if overfilled.

Answer (score 1):

If by water filter you mean a reverse osmosis water filter, end product similar to distilled water, then yes, you can use that.

Other water filters, including reverse osmosis with "remineralization" after the RO would not be suitable, unless you add a tap to pull RO water before it's remineralized.

Brand of distilled water? If any product should be utterly brand-neutral, that's it. The cheapest and most expensive brands are identical, other than how much money you waste on brand image and marketing. 2 hydrogen, one oxygen, and nothing else...

It's fairly easy to make a solar still to produce your own distilled water (it does not need to boil in the usual sense, just pass through the vapor stage and condense. Thus, it's not a difficult solar project.)